# Replacing a string with empty line

Tags: vim, sed, vi

I have a file which has 2000 lines of data (file name is data.tsv). I want to replace the string with empty line where there is a matching pattern, in my case is `PMC:`

How can I do with Vim or other sed command?

Thanks,

Rio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With vim you can do it like this:

```
:g/PMC:/normal S
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/.*PMC:.*//' data.tsv
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

```
:%s/.*PMC:.*//
```

where the '%' means 'every line' and the 's' is subsitute.  An alternate:

```
:g/PMC:/s/.*//
```

where the 'g/PMC:/' is short for 'global if line contains "PMC:"' and the 's/.*//' means 'match anything and replace it with the empty string'